# Add date from the file name for multiple files in one df in R

Tags: r

I am trying to save multiple csv files in one df and include a new column with the date of the file in the df. I already read all the files to get one df but I can't add the date column per file. Im using the next code

```
ccn_files <- list.files(pattern = '*.csv', path = "input/CCN/") ##Creates a list of all the files

ccn_data_raw <- do.call("rbind",  ##Apply the bind to the files
                  lapply(ccn_files, ##call the list
                  function(x)  ##apply the next function
                     read.csv(paste("input/CCN/", x, sep=''),fill = T, header = TRUE, 
                      skip = 4)))
```

I was also able to get the date from all the files in a vector using this line

```
test <- ymd(substr(ccn_files,14,19))
```

How can I add this line inside the first chunk of code so it does what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
ccn_data_raw <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, lapply(ccn_files, 
   function(x) read.csv(paste("input/CCN/", x, sep=''),fill = TRUE, 
               header = TRUE, skip = 4)), date = test))
```

Or using `purrr` functions :

```
library(purrr)
ccn_data_raw <- map2_df(map(ccn_files, function(x)
               read.csv(paste("input/CCN/", x, sep=''), fill = TRUE, header = TRUE, 
               skip = 4)), test, cbind)
```

Comment: Just a question. Does the code add the date to the column based on the length of the file? I'm just confirming because I got the dates in test but there could be x files and y rows.

Comment: No, the date gets added to the file irrespective of number of rows. Only criteria is `length(ccn_files)` and `length(test)` should be equal which should always be true since `test` is derived from `ccn_files`.